# Upgrading rails 4.2.8 to 5.0.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, render, upgrade

I am in a process of upgrading my old rails app built with `rails 4.2.8` to `rails 5.0.x` (tried versions of rails 5.0.1 and 5.0.7 and having the same issue).

The base rails app upgrade went fine and my base rails app is working fine. However, there is an frontend app built in angular and also one built with nodejs which have some communications channels like api and some controller to communicate with base rails app.

I am having issue in one of these controllers on line:

```
  render(:json =>  result, methods: [:mdobjectsAttributes, :blockAttributes, :entityFormTemplateBlock], :status => 200, :errorCode => 0, :layout => false)
```

The error is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `mdobjectsAttributes' for #Formtemplateblock:0x000055d7ff2a6480>):
```

So, I know I need to update/change attr_accessible and attr_protected feature in favor of Strong Parameters. And I see them in models but I am not sure does this have effect even for just `response methods` or so... I did update models to use `ApplicationRecord` instead  `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Also, I did updated `jbuilder` to last version `2.11.x`.

So, is there any suggestions for the solution? Obviously I am missing something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a preview of models and controller where errors shows.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Strong Parameters. Strong parameters are just used to whitelist incoming parameters for mass assignment to model instances when creating and updating resources. Its not at all relevant to JSON rendering. Its quite difficult to actually conclude anything since we have no idea where `:mdobjectsAttributes, :blockAttributes` are even supposed to come from and why the naming is so un-rubyeske.

Comment: legacy project... there are so mess up's.. and I am trying to upgrade the versions of ruby from 2.4.2  to 2.5.1 and rails 4.2.8 to 5.xx .... finished lot of work and base app works fine just few controllers and actions which looks like that above. Suddenly method missing if I revert the code to previous versions it works well..

Comment: If you have done branches in git I would stash or commit your changes, and then checkout whatever tag/branch was working and find the method in question. Github is also really useful for this. The camelCase tells me its more likely some application code then a gem or the framework and thus can only be aswered given said code.

Comment: Yes I am using branches. And the app is part of docker setup. So, when I change branches to older version of code it works well, just on branch where I did already some upgrade of ruby and rails I am having the issue.

Comment: @max here is a preview also of models mentioned in error and controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2-3 days investigating issue I managed to fix it by adding missing methods to the required model as attr_accessor like this:

```
attr_accessor  :blockAttributes, :entityFormTemplateBlock...
```

Because I had issues in 15 models I had to optimize my fix by creating ruby module and include it into required models.

Sample of module in `rails app/lib/custom_attr_accessors.rb`

```
module CustomAttrAccessors
    attr_accessor  :blockAttributes, :entityFormTemplateBlock..
end
```

and finally include that module into model:

```
class Formtemplate < ApplicationRecord
  include CustomAttrAccessors
.....
```